# Armazenar no BD texto estilizado para um site de noticias

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Estou criando um site de notícias e artigos e este site irá possuir um painel de controle onde os adm irão fazer o CRUD das noticias e artigos que quiserem inserir no site.

Pois bem, gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma para estilizar este texto e armazenar no banco de dados, seria salvando ele no banco já com as tags html?
se sim, poderiam me indicar uma forma fácil de se adicionar essas tags ao texto diretamente do formulário do Painel de Controle do site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você precisa é de um editor Wysiwyg. Existem diversos editores gratuitos ou open source. Um dos mais conhecidos é o TinyMCE, que você pode fazer o download em:

https://www.tinymce.com/download/

WYSIWYG é o acrônimo da expressão em inglês "what you see is what you get", cuja tradução remete a algo como "o que se vê é o que se obtém".